# Droid Explorer file manager not showing files

Tags: droid-explorer

I am using Droid Explorer (WinXP 32bit) to access my 2013 Moto X - XT1053 (Anroid 4.4.4).  But the main file explorer doesn't seem to be working.  "/" is shown, but nothing else.  My device is bootloader unlocked and rooted.  Seems like adb commands are not getting through.  I have the SDK installed as well as the official Motorola usb drivers.

Comment: This question should be reopened, especially after the last edit. It explains that the sub-folders do not load when the application opens.

Comment: In case it's related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/95894/droid-explorer-permission-denied-when-accessing-root-only-folders (by same OP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Droid Explorer to work correctly, you have to meet the following criteria:

- Rooted device (which you said you have)
- ADB USB Drivers (if on Windows)
- USB Debugging Enabled
- [Busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox) installed (I think this is where your problem is). You do not have to use the version of busybox that I linked to, but it is one that is updated frequently, and easy to install.

The console plugin, in 0.8.8.11 is very buggy and fails with a lot of devices. I have been working on an update that will be released soon (0.9.0.0) that will make the console more stable and work with any device, as long as the device meets the requirements for Droid Explorer.

Comment: Well I feel dumb!  I never looked at the "requirements" page.  Assumed I had busybox since I was rooted and root apps worked.  Thanks man!

Comment: Hmmm seems I don't have root while using explorer now :(

Comment: If you are trying to delete system files, droid explorer, for security reasons, does not allow you to just delete from there. You would have to remount the system partition as readwrite. I have thought about how to add this functionality, yet keep accidents from happening and have not come up with a food way yet. That is why you cant do it from the app right now without a manual process first.

Comment: I actually found your program looking for a way to just browse my phone's file system... I need to copy files back and forth between some app data (/data/data).  It's acting as if I don't have root access for some reason.  I can go to /data just fine in adb shell

Comment: For the sake of this question, can I suggest you create a [new question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) here, providing any information you can, including screenshots if possible. That way the answer can be scoped to the current question at hand. Also, when you start droid explorer, launch the debug console plugin, it will provide more information of what is happening.

Comment: Thank you! For me the stumbling block was not knowing BusyBox was something to install from the device side, after rooting.