# Why can't I access /data/data with Droid Explorer on my rooted phone?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, droid-explorer

For some reason, I cannot access `/data/data` with [Droid Explorer](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer)<sup><sup>**1**</sup></sup> after [adbd insecure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.adbd) install on my phone.<sup><sup>**2**</sup></sup> I CAN access the folder via `adb` and `su` command.

What am I missing? (I want to modify a game file more conveniently)

Rooted stock Samsung Galaxy S5, hacked to work with Xposed framework.

---

<sup><sup>**1**</sup></sup><sub>Note that *DroidExplorer* is ***NOT*** an app running on the device, but a Windows (.NET) application accessing the device over ADB – so suggesting "another file explorer app" is not useful :)</sub>
<sup><sup>**2**</sup></sup><sub>Of course I also activated insecure mode after installing it</sub>

Comment: Does it work with other file explorers?

Comment: If you run `adb shell`, does the prompt end with a `$` or a `#`? Do you have to run `su` to get the `#`? Background: Just *installing* the *adb insecure* app doesn't change things. You must run it and enable insecure mode.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for all the answers, let me be more specfic. SuperThomasLab & Gokul: It does work ON the phone (Rootexplorer etc). @Izzy: Indeed, I ran Droid Explorer on my PC to access my phone. Inside Droid Explorer, you can run seperate adb shell and with "su" and some "cd"' commands, you can access /data/data. HOWEVER DroidExplorer cannot! Of course I also enabled the adbd app after installing ;-).

Comment: @user2305193 I've updated your question accordingly (and cleaned up "obsoleted comments"). One question still open from my previous comment: what does the prompt look like when you run `adb shell`? If it's a `$`, `adbd` is *not* running in insecure mode, so trouble might be located there.

Comment: @user2305193 See if this helps: **[Droid Explorer permission denied when accessing root-only folders](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/95894/droid-explorer-permission-denied-when-accessing-root-only-folders)**

Comment: Good find, @GokulNC – I'd almost go as far as to say "duplicate" to that. If OP confirms, that is :)

Comment: @"Gokul NC": I read this post and did exactly everything they said - that's what I meant by "I activated it"... unfortunately no duplicate =( my problem wasn't solved by that post. Maybe I have to run the "adb remount" command, but then again, the problem isn't the access via shell but... I guess DroidExplorer does not 'claim' the appropriate su rights? I wish I could give/pipe DroidExplorer a shell with su rights already but I don't know how...

Comment: @Izzy: if adbd is not in insecure mode I coulnd't access /data/data with adb/su shell am I right?

Comment: Not with `adb pull` and `adb push` (which I assume DroidExplorer is using), no. Using `su` from a shell would work, though. A definite answer must be given from Ryan I guess (he's the dev of DroidExplorer).